# Simulate link click from function that directs to localhost

Tags: javascript, html

So I am trying to simulate a link click when a button is clicked, but nothing seems to happen when executing the code.

```
<a id=“preface” href=https://localhost:443/6.5.1> 6.5.1 </a>
<button id=“auto” onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById(“preface”).click();
}
</script>
```

I should mention that the template file containing this code is used and executed by Golang with:

```
s1, _ := template.ParseFiles("html_file")
s1.ExecuteTemplate(w, "html_file", nil)
```

I do not know why it does not work, because when I try doing an alert action it works, while even if I try opening a window for www.google.com it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried putting https://localhost:443/6.5.1 in quotes? ie. `href="https://localhost:443/6.5.1"`

Comment: @FrankerZ I did, but if I do that then not even clicking the link manually works anymore.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how you redirect using `js`. try to use `window.location`.

Something like:

```
function myFunction() {
    var link = document.getElementById("preface").getAttribute("href");
    window.location.href = link;
}
```

**Edit**:
Plunker here:
https://plnkr.co/edit/AP7MV51LdRs43HFIQngw?p=preview

If you see in the console..network tab you should see a call to `google.co.uk`

Comment: I tried it now, but still nothing happens. I even tried putting "https://www.google.co.uk" instead of the 'link' variable and still nothing... I am really confused.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help! Apparently the problem was that the id value was written with quotes "preface". When I wrote it:

```
id = preface
```

it worked. I do not understand why, since as far as I know both href and id should have their values in quotes, but it seems that it only works this way.

Thank you again!